# Run PHP After Page Loads up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I created a facebook app recently that posts some content to the user group. If the user posts to multiple groups then I would like to display a progress bar. The HTML part of it I created a form that has got a text area and the form redirects to a post.php file. And I post to the user groups in that post.php page. As I said I use a progress bar to show the progress. But the message gets posted first and only then the progress bar works. I'm pretty sure about the progress bar that it works.

To put it short the PHP part gets executed first before the JS or the HTML. So please do help me out in overcoming this problem.

This is what I have in the post.php file :

```
    <body style = "background-color: #4ea6e6;">
    <center>
        <div style = "width: 50%; margin-top: 5%; padding: 50px; background-color: #fff;">
            <div class="input-group" style = "height: 30px;">
                <progress min = "0" max = "100" value = "50" style = "height: 30px;">

                </progress>

                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    0%
                </span>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class = "message">

            </div>

            <br>
            <div class = "alert alert-success success" style = "font-size: 18px; font-family: Muli; visibility: hidden;"><b>Great !</b> Your message was successfully posted !</div>

        </div>

    </center>
</body> <?php

    require_once 'libs/facebook.php';
    $config = array(
      'appId' => 'My app id',
      'secret' => 'my app secret',
      'fileUpload' => false, // optional
      'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
    );

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $groups = $_POST['groups'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $count = count($groups);

    for($i=1; $i<count($groups); $i++){

                $api = $facebook->api($groups[$i] . '/feed', 'post', array(
                    link => $link,
                    message => $message
                ));

                $api = $facebook->api($groups[$i]);

                $name = $api['name'];

                $j = ($i/(count($groups)-1))*100;

                ?>

                <script type = "text/javascript">
                var timeout = setTimeout(post, 0);
                function post(){

                    $('progress').attr("value" , "<?php echo $j; ?>");
                    $('.message').html("Posting to <?php echo $name; ?>");
                    $('.input-group-addon').html("<?php echo $j; ?> %");

                    if(<?php echo ($i/count($groups)); ?> != 1){
                        var timeout = setTimeout(post, 0);
                    }
                    else{
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                    }
                }

                </script>
                <?php

            }
```

Comment: "To put it short the PHP part gets executed first before the JS or the HTML" -- Of course, this is how the client-server model works.

Comment: There's always the `sleep()` function, but it seems to me that your problem is more of a conceptual one, maybe use ajax calls and delay them via JS?

Comment: @elclanrs I want to know if there is any possible way to make it work the opposite way

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute sync PHP after html and js are loaded.

BUT you can execute an XHR call to a PHP script so that once js is loaded the AJAX call starts and PHP script is executed in background

Here is [how to use AJAX with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a separate PHP file after the page has loaded, without JS, like this.

Notice that the "background image" is actually a PHP file. The PHP file will execute when it is called at the bottom of the body, after the html file and all elements above it.

You can send data to the PHP file via GET in the CSS property...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#runPHP
{ 
  background-image:url(script.php);
  display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="runPHP"></div>
</body>
</html>
```